# Передать переменную из javascript в php.

Tags: php, javascript

Пробую вот так:

var name="OKO";
$.post('sec.php',{name1:name},function(data){});

в php файле хочу вывести на экран :

<?php
echo $_POST['name1'];
?>

почему не работает ? помогите исправить

Comment: А как вы узнали, что не работает? У вас функция-обработчик не делает ничего с ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что надо просто сабмитить форму, тут вам аякс не нужен

```
<form method="post"><input name="name1" value="нужное значене" /></form>
```

Сначала надо освоить базу, а уж потом углубляться....

Answer (score 0):

все верно подметил [[@Fike](/users/16095/fike)](/users/16095/fike), напишите так

```
$.post('sec.php',{name1:name},function(data){alert(data)});
```

И проверьте, правильный ли путь к файлу sec.php

Comment: но почему я не могу вывести на экран это на второй странице?
или как это сделать?

Comment: на какой второй странице  ? :) это ajax запрос, вывод второй страницы приходит обработчику.

Comment: @hil400k, представьте, что аякс-запрос - это просто открытие новой невидимой вкладки в браузере. Сервер отдает точно такой же ответ, как и при прямом запросе, но все это происходит абсолютно невидимо для пользователя, и ответ оказывается в переменной яваскрипта, а не у пользователя перед глазами.